# Memory allocation from 64 bit process inside WOW64 process using VirtualAllocEx

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to allocate memory inside a WOW64 process remotely from a 64 bit process using the Win32 API `VirtualAllocEx`. If I let the OS determine where to allocate the memory inside the WOW64 process by setting `lpAddress` to `NULL`, will the API consider that it is allocating memory inside a WOW64 process or will the API treat the process like a normal 64 bit process and potentially allocate the memory outside the 32 bit address range? In other words: Is it safe to cast the returned pointer to a `DWORD` without losing data?

I'm especially worried because I noticed that some dlls like `wow64base.dll` are located outside the 32 bit address range in the WOW64 process.

If the possibility exists that `VirtualAllocEx` will return a pointer to a location beyond the 32 bit range, is there a way to enforce that it will only allocate within the 32 bit range?

Comment: *If the possibility exists that VirtualAllocEx will return a pointer to a location beyond the 32 bit range* - no, if you pass lpAddress to NULL

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to clarify: That means I can safely cast the return value to a DWORD, correct?

Comment: yes, of course, but for what you need this cast ?

Comment: I need to write the address to the PEB of the WOW process (ImageBaseAddress member), and in 32 bit PEB this can only store a 4 byte address. That's why I need to be sure that the return value of VirtualAllocEx can be stored in 4 bytes.

Comment: yes, of course by default memory will be allocated in 32bit range